# How can I disable jack sensing?

Tags: windows-8, audio

I have a HP Pavilion Desktop computer running Windows 8 64 bit. I would like to use the sound card for something other than listening to music. The speaker jack has jack sensing. The only thing that seems to activate it is the speaker connector. I understand that there is supposed to be a edit to the registry that will defeat this function. My problem is the installed Windows 8 on this computer does not have the registry entry according to HP support. I find it hard to believe that anyone would build a computer that you can't use for other sound projects. If anyone can tell me how to by pass the jack sensing I sure would appreciate it.

Comment: What sound card? Driver you using for the sound?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there currently isn't any help for Windows 8. I used a cheap USB soundcard to bypass this pointless 'feature' which is on nearly all HP/Compaq desktops. It has something to do with the soundcard driver and as your desktop isn't Windows 8 compatible (according to HP, even though it works fine in all other respects)

My card was less than $5 - Same as this [http://www.amazon.com/HDE-Channel-External-Sound-Adapter/dp/B0027EMHM6/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1366511293&sr=8-2&keywords=usb+soundcard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0027EMHM6)

If you can find the same soundcard in their newer desktops then you could use those drivers, but HP sticking to the same anything in any hardware (apart from servers) - Is very unlikely for them to do.